# I get a spare output out of nowhere

Tags: python

My code right here emits a strange output, it gives me the second part of `inp_a` even though I didn`t ask for it. couldn't find the reason why.

Thanks in advance for the help

```
inp_a = input("What`s the time you want to start from? ")
military_time = input("is it AM or PM: ").upper()
inp_b = input("How long would you like to wait? ")
day = input("What`s the day today?\nThe day must be one of the weekdays ")


inp_a = inp_a.split(":")
inp_b = inp_b.split(":")
day = day.lower()

if military_time == "AM":
  inp_a[0] = inp_a[0]
elif military_time == "PM":
  inp_a[0] = int(inp_a[0]) + 12
  inp_a[0] = str(inp_a[0])



try:
  convert_a1 = int(inp_a[0])
  convert_a2 = int(inp_a[1])
  convert_b1 = int(inp_b[0])
  convert_b2 = int(inp_b[1])
except:
  print("-"*50)
  print("One of the inputs is incorrect, try again")
  


while True:
  if day == "sunday":
    break
  elif day == "monday":
    break
  elif day == "tuesday":
    break
  elif day == "wednsday":
    break
  elif day == "thursday":
    break
  elif day == "friday":
    break
  elif day == "saturday":
    break
  else:
    print(day,"is not one of the weekdays try again")
    quit()

rl_time = int(inp_a[0])*60 + int(input(inp_a[1]))
time2add = int(inp_b[0]*60) + int(input(inp_b[1]))

result = rl_time + time2add
hh = result // 60
mm = result % hh
```

Comment: Please provide your input, as well as actual vs. expected output. FYI the term 'weekday' typically means Monday-Friday, i.e. excluding weekend days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this part of the code:

```
rl_time = int(inp_a[0])*60 + int(input(inp_a[1]))
time2add = int(inp_b[0]*60) + int(input(inp_b[1]))
```

You're calling `input` again for no reason, and `input` prompts the user with its argument (in this case `inp_a[1]`, which is the extra output you're seeing).  If you enter something it'll do the same thing on the next line with `inp_b[1]`.

Here's a fixed version of the full thing -- you can simplify a lot by just doing the `int` conversion once, rather than converting to int, converting back to str, back to int, etc.  You also had your `while` loop in the wrong spot if the intent is to re-prompt the user for new values when something is incorrect.

```
while True:
    inp_a = input("What`s the time you want to start from? ")
    military_time = input("is it AM or PM: ").upper()
    inp_b = input("How long would you like to wait? ")
    day = input("What`s the day today?\n"
        "The day must be one of the weekdays"
    ).lower()

    try:
        ah, am = map(int, inp_a.split(":"))
        bh, bm = map(int, inp_b.split(":"))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print("Time must be entered as HH:MM")
        continue
    if day not in ("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"):
        print(f"{day.title()} is not one of the weekdays, try again.")
        continue
    break
   
if military_time == "PM":
    ah += 12


rl_time = ah * 60 + am
time2add = bh * 60 + bm

result = rl_time + time2add
hh, mm = divmod(result, 60)
```